# How to - grouping a list by key and split the values using streams Java 8

Tags: java, group-by, java-stream

I need to group the ABC List, while doing this I also wanted to split the value.
Input:

```java
List<ABC> list = new ArrayList<>();

ABC A1 = new ABC();
A1.setName("OO");
A1.setVal("OO111,OO222,OO333"); // split this while grouping
list.add(A1);

ABC A2 = new ABC();
A2.setName("OO");
A2.setVal("OO1");
list.add(A2);

ABC A3 = new ABC();
A3.setName("YY");
A3.setVal("1333,11444");
list.add(A3);
```

Output:

```java
Map<String, List<String>> postsPerType;
//Group by Name: ex: OO & YY. Split the Value by "," and add it to list
     Key: 00 Values: List: "OO111","OO222","OO333","OO1"
     Key: YY Values: List: "1333","11444"
```

Please suggest, thanks.

Comment: Basically you split a string at the commas using the split method. For example : String originalString = "OO111,OO222,OO333"; List<String> splitList = Arrays.asList(originalString.split(","));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is using `groupingBy` and `collectingAndThen` collectors.

```
list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    ABC::getName,
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.mapping(ABC::getVal, toList()),
                            strings -> strings.stream()
                                     .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(",")))
                                     .collect(toList()))
            ));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Java 9+, you can use `Collectors.flatMapping()` as `groupingBy`'s downstream:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ABC::getName,
                    Collectors.flatMapping(a -> Arrays.stream(a.getVal().split(",")), 
                                           Collectors.toList())));
```

That should produce exactly your desired result.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can chain a `reducing` collector to the `groupingBy` collector to get what you need:

```
Map<String, List<String>> postsPerType =
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ABC::getName,
                                       Collectors.reducing(new ArrayList<String>(),
                                                           a -> Arrays.asList(a.getVal().split(",")),
                                                           (l1,l2)-> {
                                                             List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(); 
                                                             l.addAll(l1);
                                                             l.addAll (l2);
                                                             return l;
                                                           })));
```

This produces the following `Map`:

```
{YY=[1333, 11444], OO=[OO111, OO222, OO333, OO1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
record ABC(String name, String val) {
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getVal() { return val; }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ABC> list = List.of(
        new ABC("00", "00111,00222,00333"),
        new ABC("00", "001"),
        new ABC("YY", "1333,11444"));
    Map<String, List<String>> postsPerType = new HashMap<>();
    for (ABC e : list)
        postsPerType.computeIfAbsent(e.getName(), k -> new ArrayList<>())
            .addAll(Arrays.asList(e.getVal().split(",")));
    System.out.println(postsPerType);
}
```

output:

```
{YY=[1333, 11444], 00=[00111, 00222, 00333, 001]}
```